# Adding holes simultaneously within mesh

Tags: modeling

Im trying to add multiple holes within my mesh, so I divided it up, and then used cylinders shapes to make the holes. On the top image I used the Boolean operation.
And on the bottom image, I subdivided one of the rectangles and used the looptool method with the circle. Once I add a subdivision modifier I am getting weird result with the Boolean but the operation holes, but the bottom Hole looks more acceptable once cleaned up. Is one or the other method the correct way?

[image]

Comment: Instead of using the cylinders, inset the faces with "i", the subdivision modifier/ subdividing then makes perfect circles, once you sharpen the edges (with edge crease/ loopcuts)

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. 

So I tried what you set insetting a face on my mesh. I'm not understanding your next step, can you please post a screen shot?

Thank you.

https://imgur.com/9Tl4Fth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the face you want holes on
2. Inset all faces by pressing "i"
3. Extrude all faces by pressing "e"
4. Extrude all faces by pressing "e", press "g" and drag them down
5. Extrude all faces by pressing "e"

(3. and 5. sharpen the edges, so you don't have to add Loopcuts/Edge Creases)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank for your prompt response, Now I saw the wrong modelling approach I was venturing into. It's easy to watch a clip on YT with a incorrect technique and learn the wrong way. Lucky for this forum can save the day!

Cheers!