# Hard-surface modeling of phone

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I make the model of phone. I use hard-surface modelling and now I have problem to make speakers holes. As you can see on screenshots something is wrong with faces after boolean modifier. As for me the geometry main body of phone is right.
Tell me pleace what I must make with model for obtain right surface.

[image]
[image]

And one more question: is it right to modeling the phone or things like that using hard-surface modeling?

Comment: Dublicate of: [Adding holes simultaneously within mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165281/adding-holes-simultaneously-within-mesh). It is a way to do it, but creates bad geometry, which creates problems later down the road with texturing, animation, other people (or yourself) working on the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "hard surface", but have some experience with boolean. So, you are trying to create pits by intersecting the cylinders with the phone bottom (IE: The cylinders are one mesh separate from the phone mesh and you are not using an array modifier)?

I notice that there are ALOT of modifiers on the phone, one of these may be causing the faliure.

Well, here's what I think you should try:

1, cancel the boolean modifier and join the two meshes (object mode, select cylinders, then phone, press Ctrl+J or find join in object menu).
2, enter edit mode and select the cylinders.
3, intersect (knife).
4, select all and merge by distance (at the default small distance).
5, If I remember right, select and delete the top half of the cylinder.
6, select and delete (only faces) the circles covering the holes.

Let me know if this works!