# Beginner: How to make a mirrored "recesses'' in a shape of a spheres into an object mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am complete beginner and since I dont know how to properly ask the question, I am not having luck with googling it. I can show you what I mean with pictures.

I am trying to make an egg shape with spherical holes in its mesh, but cannot really figure it out. Reference picture of the "holes" is this:

[image: ball]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165281/adding-holes-simultaneously-within-mesh/165326#165326

Answer (score 1):

The following method works better when the faces are evenly spaced quads

1. Add a sphere
2. Go to edit mode
3. Press "A" to select all faces
4. Press "I" once or twice
5. Scale the individual faces down
6. Press "E" to extrude all faces
7. Press "S" to scale the faces to the center
8. After scaling it towards the sphere center apply
9. Add a Subdivision Surface Modifier

I just found a tutorial that has another nice method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJXsgan3Juc
[image]